# Get the Location Name in onLocationChanged(Location location) method

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gmsmapview, google-location-services

I want to get the location-name inside `onLocationChanged(Location location)()` method. We can get the `Latitude` and `Longitude` from onLocationChanged(Location location) as `location.getLatitude();` and `location.getLongitude();` **But i need the location name**. It has no method of getting location name. Can I get that?

I am doing in this way :

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           double la = location.getLatitude();
           double lo= location.getLongitude();
           // location Name? 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Amar there is a method in geocoder class getFromLocation (lat,lng,maxResults)
which gives a timed out exception sometimes.It has been a bug for the geocoder.
So instead of calling that method just make a request asynchronously in locationChanged callback method

```
  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       new LocationAdressAsync(this,this).execute("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + location.getLongitude() + "," +  location.getLatitude()+ "&sensor=true");
}
```

Comment: I think it is not a good way of doing this. Sending a request to network for location!!!

Comment: getFromLocation (lat,lng,maxResults) which too sends a request to network for location which will not work everytime because of its timeout exception due to network error or any other cause.So in my view i think of this one.Thank you

Comment: I am not using `geocoder` that has a method `locality` to get the location. But I believe that there will be a way here....

Comment: @BasheerKohli what about this `LocationAdressAsync`. It not in impoting list.

Comment: its my async task class created to do background operation.